# Check if the atom is a lowercase letter

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm doing it like this:

```
foo(N) :-
        name(N, [Code]),
        name(a, [CodeA]),
        name(z, [CodeZ]),
        CodeA =< Code,
        Code  =< CodeZ.
```

Is there a way that doesn't feel like such a workaroud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
atom_is_lower(N) :-
    atom_chars(N, [L]),
    char_type(L, lower).
```

- [atom_chars](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.20%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipatom.html%27%29%29) converts the atom into a list of characters.
- [char_type](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.21%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/chartype.html%27%29%29) checks the type of a character.

Note that the second part (char_type) is necessary because a single-character atom can be a number (for example).

Comment: links appear to be broken :(

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the built-in `char_type/2` and if it encounters a type error (e.g. when the input is longer than one symbol) and throws an exception then convert the exception to failure.

```
atom_is_lower(Atom) :-
    catch(char_type(Atom, lower), _, fail).
```

This solution can also *generate* lowercase letters:

```
?- atom_is_lower(A).
A = a ;
A = b ;
A = c ;
A = d ;
A = e ;
...
```